# Finding a point on a perpendicular vector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object that I want to move perpendicular to it.

What am I doing:

- I determine the middle Point between P1 and P2
- I define the perpendicular vector

How can I find the point I need depending on the mouse position? (knowing X I have to find Y and vice versa)

[image]

Comment: Since you say you already know the perpendicular vector it basically comes down to "How to map the mouse position onto that vector?" => Would this answer your question: [How to find the closest point on a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905268/how-to-find-closest-point-on-line)

Answer (score 0):

Let `P` the middle point, `D` the perpendicular direction vector, `M` the mouse point and `Q` the unknown point. We express that a moving point along `D` forms a right angle by

```
(P + t D - M).D = 0
```

which gives us

```
t = (M - P).D / D²
```

and

```
Q = P + t D
```